# Creating a "like" url/button for Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, serialization, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an API to use for an iPhone app. In order to like a picture, I'm assuming I need to embed a url in my serializer that can be used to add a like to a photo. Could someone please help me implement this?

I am able to view the url, but I'm not sure how to pass the photo's id to the view. This is where I've gotten so far:

***views.py:***

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def like_create_api(request, photo_id):
    serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.object.content_object = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=photo_id)
        serializer.object.likers.add(request.user)
        serializer.save()
        return RestResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return RestResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

***serializers.py:***

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likers = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True, view_name='user_account_detail_api', read_only=True,
        lookup_field='username')
    like_url = LikeUrlField("like_create_api")

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['like_url', 'id', 'slug', 'photo', 'likers']
```

***models.py:***

```
class Photo(HashtagMixin, TimeStampedModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category")
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name='likers', blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'photos'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.slug)
```

***urls.py:***

```
url(r'^like/$', 'api.views.like_create_api',
        name='like_create_api'),
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a serializer for validation just save the like relation.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def like_create_api(request, photo_id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo.objects.all(), pk=photo_id)
    photo.likers.add(request.user)
    serializer = PhotoSerializer(photo)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `(?P<photo_id>\d+)/$` in url?

Something like this:

```
url(r'^like/(?P<photo_id>\d+)/$', 'api.views.like_create_api',
    name='like_create_api'),
```

UP: If you need to fetch *post form* parameter (`request.POST.get('photo_id', '')`) then your view must be like this:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def like_create_api(request):
    ...
        serializer.object.content_object = get_object_or_404(Photo,
            id=request.POST.get('photo_id', ''))
    ...
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to post the data: `"detail": "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"`. Any ideas?